# Aun cuando + forma del verbo

Tags: conjunciones

Bueno, he entendido que la subordinada concesiva con *aunque* puede hallarse en indicativo o en subjuntivo. Incluso he encontrado algunos ejemplos con *aunque* + condicional. Ahora me gustaría saber si se puede usar el condicional y el futuro con la conjunción *aun cuando*. Tengo aquí cinco libros de los escritores españoles y latinoamericanos y he encontrado una sola frase con *aun cuando* + subjuntivo.

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Tanto el indicativo como el subjuntivo pueden usarse con "aun cuando" cuando esta locución conjuntiva puede ser reemplazada, si bien con un significado algo diferente,  por el "aunque" que introduce situaciones inciertas:

- Vendré aun cuando no **tenga** ganas. (Vendré aunque no tenga ganas.)
- Iría aun cuando no **tuviera** ganas. (Iría aunque no tuviera ganas.)

En "aun cuando" el componente concesivo es "aun", que modifica la conjunción temporal "cuando" y permite, como en los ejemplos anteriores, el uso del subjuntivo.

Sin embargo, con el fututo del indicativo y el condicional "cuando" vuelve a ser la conjunción rectora y, en esa condición, inhibe el uso de esos tiempos como no gramaticales. En este caso, "aun" sólo significa "inclusive". Del mismo modo que estas oraciones **no** son gramaticales:

- X Vendré cuando tendré ganas.
- X Iría cuando tendría ganas.

**tampoco** son gramaticales estas otras:

- X Vendré aun cuando no tendré ganas.
- X Iría aun cuando no tendría ganas.

Como regla general:

- "aun cuando" (= inclusive cuando) + indicativo: significado temporal
- "aun cuando" (= aunque) + subjuntivo: significado concesivo

Excepcionalmente, puede encontrarse después de "aun cuando" el uso tentativo del condicional en lugar del presente del indicativo. Así, en lugar del más categórico:

- Aun cuando sé qué hacer, en este caso prefiero no actuar.

alguien más modesto podría decir:

- Aun cuando **sabría** qué hacer (de hecho, sé qué hacer), en este caso prefiero no actuar.

Comment: Buena explicación, Gustavson. Por cierto, [guifa sugiere](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2571/1674) usar el formato _* texto_ para marcar que es erróneo. Lo digo porque lo de _X texto_ también es entendible, pero siendo él académico parece que ese es el estándar.

Comment: Es verdad, pero me salía un *bullet point* y debí recurrir a una cruz.

Comment: Si no quieres que el markdown dé significado a estos elementos, escápalos: `\*` funciona. Lo mismo con las listas: si pones `1.` le pone sangría, pero con `1\.` ya no.